# How to make an interactive video progress bar in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I can't think of a good way to make an interactive video progress bar using three.js.. and I can't find an example of it being done anywhere.

I can draw the progress of the video pretty well (a plane with a canvas texture ) but selecting a new progress point with a raycast is what I can't figure out. I've tried checking the world coordinates ( intersects[ 0 ].point ) on clicks, the bar ranges from -3x to 2x but I don't know how to translate that into 100% (my math isn't good enough). And this also seems like a bad idea as it depends on keeping the controls fixed

Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the coordinates of the plane and the raycast hit, it seems like you're already on it.

To translate -3x to 2x into percentages, do this:

```
value = (x + 3) / 5; // will return something between 0 and 1,
                     // multiply by 100 to get percentage
```

It's basically offset compensation divided by the plane length.

Comment: nice! your math was exact :)

Comment: Yup, it's a fairly common calculation: get a part of something and divide it by the full thing. ;)